# Swift: How to remove duplicates from my table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, duplicates, tableview

Problem here is that I'm getting duplicates in my table view and I know why but I don't know how to fix it and implement a different system.

My app is a blog reader that reads from a MYSQL database using PHP to send JSON to my Swift app. My table view has two sections, one for all the objects from the database and second section is for when I click the follow button on the cells, basically move the objects from mainArray to followedArray. Each section is using an array so for example I move all the objects from mainArray to followedArray and I update the table I get all those objects again in mainArray, obviously because the mainarray is empty and the code is just doing its job.

So how can I implement a better system so when the user moves the objects from one section to another (or from mainArray to followedArray) mainArray doesn't get repopulated with the same objects that it had and are now in followedArray.

Here is the code I use.

MainController.swift - Class where Tableview is at

```
var mainArray = [Blog]()
var followedArray = [Blog]()

// Title for Header
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

        if section == 0 {
            return "Followed Blogs"
        }
        else {
            return "All Blogs"
        }
    }
    return "Filtered Blogs"
}

// Number of Rows in Section
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

        if section == 0 {

            return followedArray.count
        }
        else if (section == 1) {

            return mainArray.count
        }
    }
    return filteredArray.count
}

// CellForRowAt indexPath
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as! CustomCell

    if cell != cell {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    // Configuring the cell
    var blogObject: Blog

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            blogObject = followedArray[indexPath.row] 
            cell.populateCell(blogObject, isFollowed: true, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            blogObject = mainArray[indexPath.row] 
            cell.populateCell(blogObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
    }
    else {
        blogObject = filteredArray[indexPath.row] 
        cell.populateCell(blogObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
    }

    return cell
}

// Follow Button
@IBAction func followButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton!) {

    // Adding row to tag
    let buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
    if let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) {

        // Showing Status Labels
        let cell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = false

        // Change Follow to Following
        (sender as UIButton).setImage(UIImage(named: "follow.png")!, for: .normal)
        cell.followButton.isHidden = true
        cell.followedButton.isHidden = false

        // Checking wether to import from mainArray or filteredArray to followedArray
        if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

            self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

            // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
            followedArray.insert(mainArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)
            myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

            // ----- Removing Cell from mainArray -----
            mainArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 1)], with: .fade)

            self.myTableView.endUpdates()

            myTableView.reloadData()

            // After Updating Table, Save the Archived to UserDefaults
            saveUserDefaults()
        }
        else {

            self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

            // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
            let blogObject: Blog = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
            let indexOfObjectInArray = mainArray.index(of: blogObject)

            followedArray.insert(blogObject, at: 0)

            // ----- Removing Cell from filteredArray -----
            filteredArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            mainArray.remove(at: indexOfObjectInArray!)
            let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 0)], with: .fade)

            self.myTableView.endUpdates()

            myTableView.reloadData()

            // After Updating Table, Save the Archived to UserDefaults
            saveUserDefaults()
        }
    }
}


// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveDataFromServer() {

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for jsonObject in jsonArray {

            if let blog = Blog.createGame(from: jsonObject as AnyObject) {

                mainArray.append(blog)
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Blog.swift - Handles the blogs objects where I user NSCoder too

```
import UIKit

class Blog: NSObject, NSCoding {

var blogName: String!
var blogStatus1: String!
var blogStatus2: String!
var blogURL: String!
var blogID: String!
var blogType: String!
var blogDate: String!
var blogPop: String!

static func createBlog(from jsonObject: AnyObject) -> Blog? {

    guard let bID: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "id") as? String,
        let bName: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogName") as? String,
        let bStatus1: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogStatus1") as? String,
        let bStatus2: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogStatus2") as? String,
        let bURL: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogURL") as? String,
        let bType: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogType") as? String,
        let bDate: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogDate") as? String,
        let bPop: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogPop") as? String

        else {
          print("Error: (Creating Blog Object)")
          return nil
}

let blog = Blog()
    blog.blogName = bName
    blog.blogStatus1 = bStatus1
    blog.blogStatus2 = bStatus2
    blog.blogURL = bURL
    blog.blogID = bID
    blog.blogType = bType
    blog.blogDate = bDate
    blog.blogPop = bPop
    return blog
}

convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init ()
    self.blogName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogName") as! String
    self.blogStatus1 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogStatus1") as! String
    self.blogStatus2 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogStatus2") as! String
    self.blogURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogURL") as! String
    self.blogID = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogID") as! String
    self.blogType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogType") as! String
    self.blogDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogDate") as! String
    self.blogPop = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogPop") as! String
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(blogName, forKey: "blogName")
    aCoder.encode(blogStatus1, forKey: "blogStatus1")
    aCoder.encode(blogStatus2, forKey: "blogStatus2")
    aCoder.encode(blogURL, forKey: "blogURL")
    aCoder.encode(blogID, forKey: "blogID")
    aCoder.encode(blogType, forKey: "blogType")
    aCoder.encode(blogDate, forKey: "blogDate")
    aCoder.encode(blogPop, forKey: "blogPop")
 }
}
```

Is there a way to check before repopulating mainArray to see whats in followedArray and whatever is missing or added to the database to import and not create duplicates because new blogs will be added and the users will transfer blogs across sections so this is a major issue that I am having.

Would appreciate the help as I am still learning Swift, thank you.

Comment: What is the model class for the table view? Already there in the model class we shouldn't have any duplicates.

Comment: After the objects have been transferred from mainArray to followdArray, mainArray is empty so it gets repopulated

Comment: Is the idea that you want to save the "list of followed blogs" between uses of the app?

Comment: Yes as well as mainArray because thats where initially all the objects are and where they're added too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend saving an unique identifier for the blogs which should be in the followed category into an array and on each reload of the tableView, move the proper cells to the correct section.

You seem to be using [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) but have no modifications to them. Using my method the only array that is required to be saved into and loaded from the UserDefaults is the list of followed blogs. The rest default to the main list, even as new blogs show up.

you will need one more array:

```
var mainArray = [Blog]()
var followedArray = [Blog]()
var followedIdentifiers = [String]()
```

or whatever datatype the identifier will be in

You could also use a `Set` as you want no duplicates in the followedIdentifiers

```
var followedIdentifiers = Set<String>()
```

Here are modifications to the relevant parts of your code (My changes marked with `<----`):

```
// Checking whether to import from mainArray or filteredArray to followedArray
if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

    self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

    // Save identifier into followedIdentifier array <--------------
    self.followedIdentifiers.insert(mainArray[indexPath.row].blogID)

    // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
    followedArray.insert(mainArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)
    myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

    // ----- Removing Cell from mainArray -----
    mainArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
    self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 1)], with: .fade)

    self.myTableView.endUpdates()

    myTableView.reloadData()

    // After Updating Table, Save the Archived to UserDefaults
    saveUserDefaults()
} else {

    self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

    // Remove identifier into followedIdentifier array <------------
    self.followedIdentifiers.remove(followedArray[indexPath.row].blogID)

    // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
    let blogObject: Blog = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
    let indexOfObjectInArray = mainArray.index(of: blogObject)

    followedArray.insert(blogObject, at: 0)

    // ----- Removing Cell from filteredArray -----
    filteredArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    mainArray.remove(at: indexOfObjectInArray!)
    let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
    self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 0)], with: .fade)

    self.myTableView.endUpdates()

    myTableView.reloadData()

    // After Updating Table, Save the Archived to UserDefaults
    saveUserDefaults()
}

// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveDataFromServer() {

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Clear the arrays      <-------------
        self.followedArray = [Blog]()
        self.mainArray = [Blog()]

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for jsonObject in jsonArray {

            if let blog = Blog.createBlog(from: jsonObject as AnyObject) {
                // Check if identifiers match <------------
                if followedIdentifiers.contains(blog.blogID) {
                    self.followedArray.append(blog)
                } else {
                    self.mainArray.append(blog)
                }

            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

In order for this to work **across sessions** you must have something similar to this in your `saveUserDefaults()`

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Array(self.followedIdentifiers), forKey: "someName")
```

and this where you load from UserDefaults

```
self.followedIdentifiers = Set(UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "someName"))
```

Comment: What can I do with Set instead of an Array?

Comment: A set is a collection which guarantees a single instance of an object. Basically, an array which you cannot add duplicates. As you are doing a blog and I assume order matters, maybe [NSMutableOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableorderedset) would be better

Comment: Its not duplicates in the same array, after the objects have been transferred from mainArray to followedArray, mainArray is empty so it gets repopulated while followedArray has those objects that were transferred, aside from the new objects that will be added in the future. The user picks which cell to transfer.

Comment: @BroSimple where is `retrieveDataFromServer` called?

Comment: also I see `saveUserDefaults` but you have not edited anything in the database

Comment: `retrieveDataFromServer()` is called in `viewDidLoad` and for `saveUserDefaults` what do you mean? I have a `loadUserDefaults` in `viewDidLoad` as well. Not really supposed to edit anything just to save how the user left the arrays after transferring across. Is that what you meant?

Comment: in order to modify user defaults, you must make edits and loads such as [here](http://www.thomashanning.com/userdefaults/).

Comment: What do you mean edits? I'm just saving the array when the user clicks the follow or unfollow button and load it in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: you are saving the arrays to memory, but not across app sessions, which is what [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) is for. Next time the app is opened the arrays are back to how they started, unless you update the information on the server

Comment: I'm confused with saving across app sessions? I'm archiving the arrays and then saving them to UserDefaults and loading them on viewDidLoad and it's working as intended, the server is just to get the objects that I have inserted in the MYSQL database and send them through JSON.

Comment: I rewrote my answer, maybe this method is more of what you were looking for.

Comment: Okay so what your method is saying, if the user moves any cells from mainArray to followedArray to save followedArray and when mainArray is getting refreshed to check if followedArray has any of those cells and then not insert them in mainArray as followedArray already has them?

Comment: When the tableview is getting refreshed clear the mainArray AND followedArray. Download the new data. if any of the data matches the saved Identifiers place it in the followedArray. the rest are put into the mainArray. Then do the usual displaying of the tableview from those arrays. If a user hits the follow button, add the identifier to the list of followed identifiers. and move the item from the mainArray to followedArray, and reload the tableview

Comment: So how would I match the identifiers? Not familiar with any swift code to do that. Also, each blog has an id called `blogID` so I can basically use that, can I? Another thing, how do you call the entire blog object by just the `blogID`?

Comment: Yup that sounds perfect. It probably is a string so just loop through the `followedIdentifier` array and check if the string matches any. Alternatively If you use a `Set` you can ensure no duplicate  IDs are added, and you can use `followedIdentifier.contains(stringToCheckFor)`.

Shouldn't need to call any Blog objects with only the blog ID. You will have an array of Blogs and will check their identifiers against the saved ones, then move them accordingly.

Comment: I will write some actual code later instead of just explaining.

Comment: Just a comment here... the full list of "blog" data is being retrieved every time the app starts. Just track and save the "blogID" identifiers, not the whole "blog" data objects. This will also let you get rid of all the encode/decode stuff.

Comment: @JustinOroz Thank you that would help me greatly.

Comment: @DonMag it's a lot more efficient that way just checking the `blogID` instead of using NSCoder. Just need to learn how to do all of this.

Comment: @JustinOroz Hey thanks for the detailed response, learning a lot. Sorry I was at work. I tried your code and the app crashed, showing in the logs these two messages of the same error. `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Also for loadUserDefaults() when I load `setValue(self.followedIdentifiers, forKey: "someName")`, that goes in viewDidLoad as it was?

Comment: @JustinOroz Okay so I tried adding the code to retrieve `setValue(self.followedIdentifiers, forKey: "followedID")` but it crashes with the error `[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object {(
)} as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key followedID`. I error I mentioned in the last comment is not showing, probably due to not loading user defaults as I am doing it now and its giving a different crash.

Comment: @BroSimple whoops forgot to mention that UserDefaults only accepts certain types. You will need to cast the Set as an array when saving using `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Array(self.followedIdentifiers), forKey: "followedID")` then read it back with `self.followedIdentifiers = Set(UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "followedID"))`

Comment: @JustinOroz now it's back to the same crash `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: I would need more info, where did it crash, what value was it trying to unwrap

Comment: @JustinOroz So I found where the crash happens, when I click the follow button, the line you told me to add `self.followedIdentifiers.insert(mainArray[indexPath.row].blogID)`

Comment: because my line `self.followedIdentifiers.insert(mainArray[indexPath.row].blogID)` and yours following it `followedArray.insert(mainArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)` have essentially the same variables, it sounds like your Blog object blogID is nil for some reason

Comment: @JustinOroz could it be that it's not accessing blogID correctly? Because I can print out mainArray, shouldn't blogID be in there then?

Comment: @BroSimple if you can print out mainArray, you should be able to see a value for blogID, yes.